# Controls for image in quill editor

Tags: quill

I want to add controls over images in quill editor, just basic buttons like `left`, `center`, `right`, after digging codebase couldn't find clues on how to do that.

If I try to inject any dom into editor quill immediately understands that it shouldnt be there and normalizes to text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align left, right or center the line the image is on (using the `align` format), but not just the image itself. Quill does not permit arbitrary changes to its contents so the normalization are you are seeing is expected.